# Login second user in background on startup

Tags: ubuntu, boot, ubuntu-22.04

I want to login second user (admin) in background. For first user `user` I have in `/etc/gdm3/custom.conf`:

```
[daemon]
# Uncomment the line below to force the login screen to use Xorg
WaylandEnable=false

# Enabling automatic login
#  AutomaticLoginEnable = true
#  AutomaticLogin = user1

# Enabling timed login
  TimedLoginEnable = true
  TimedLogin = user
  TimedLoginDelay = 10
```

For login `admin` in background I have in `/etc/rc.local`:

```
#!/bin/sh -e

#su -l admin -c "export DISPLAY=:2 && xinit && gnome-session"
sudo su -l admin -c "xinit"

exit 0
```

But this isn't working. I want the `admin` user to login in the background at startup, so that I can switch to him anytime via the GUI

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas I have a home server that acts as a multimedia center with the option of displaying movies on projectors (KODI). There is also samba, ftp, download manager, RAID, WWW. `User` is only for KODI, and `admin` is to be used for such advanced work. The `admin` login is intended to running download managers in the background, so that no windows will be visible on the media center.

Comment: The `admin` user does not need to log in with root privileges

Comment: Sweet!  Thanks for the response. :) I KNEW there had to be something there that I was not getting.